# DWR - can't marshall enum?

Tags: grails, groovy, marshalling, dwr

No matter what I try, this keeps failing. What am I doing wrong, here?

```
package com.example
class ClassToMarshall{
   SomeEnum myEnum
}

enum SomeEnum{
A,
B
}
```

**resources.xml:**

```
   <dwr:configuration>
        <dwr:convert type="bean" class="com.example.**">
            <dwr:exclude method="metaClass"/>
        </dwr:convert>
        <dwr:convert type="enum" class="com.example.SomeEnum">
            <dwr:exclude method="metaClass"/>
        </dwr:convert>
    </dwr:configuration>
```

However, when I call `MyService.myMethod({myEnum: "A"})`, I'm receiving `Throwable throwable`. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all correct. If you have some other exception, you'll get the generic `Error error` prompt unless you enable marshalling of exceptions.

If you add this to your configuration:

```
<dwr:configuration>
    <dwr:convert class="java.lang.Exception" type="exception"/>
    <dwr:convert class="java.lang.StackTraceElement" type="bean"/>
</dwr:configuration>
```

You'll probably see an error that isn't marshalling related.